# Is it possible to deploy multiple ( many ) PhantomJS instances via Amazon Web Servises?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Starting point. A web scraping application that deploys several PhantomJS executables on Windows10 that collect data through CSS queries which is later parsed and stored in a local MongoDB database.

Now, I want to scale the scraping application to maybe 100+ PhantomJS executables to continuously scrape data from websites.

Is it possible to deploy such an application, controlled via a central Java application, via Amazon Web Services?

Comment: Absolutely, its just a question of how. You could do it from Lambdas, EC2, using something like OpsWorks...

Comment: Cool. I must investigate this further.